# How do I properly bind my model in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a class called ViewModel that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  In my XAML I have 3 textboxes that have a binding property that match my ViewModel properties:

TestsOrdered
TestsCompleted
TestsRemaining

I have a PropertyChanged event handler in my code-behind.  I have a context "MyContext" attached to the XAML window.  I am unsure why the UI does not update when I change the TestsOrdered and TestsCompleted values.  I expect the UI to update when I tab out of the textboxes but does not until I tab out of the TestsRemaining textbox.  Where is the flaw in my design ?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new ViewModel();
        //ct = new CompletionTime();
        //ct.TestsOrdered = 8000;

        vm.Name = "John Doe";
        vm.TestsCompleted = 0;
        vm.TestsOrdered = 0;
        vm.TestsRemaining = 0;

        this.MyContext.DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void btnName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.Name = "Joe";
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private int mTestsOrdered;
    private int mTestsRemaining;
    private int mTestsCompleted;

    public string Name
    {
        get { name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public int TestsOrdered
    {
        get { return mTestsOrdered; }
        set
        {
            if (mTestsOrdered != value)
            {
                mTestsOrdered = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestsOrdered"));
            }
        }
    }


    public int TestsCompleted
    {
        get { return mTestsCompleted; }
        set
        {
            if (mTestsCompleted != value)
            {
                mTestsCompleted = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestsCompleted"));
            }
        }
    }


    public int TestsRemaining
    {
        get { return TestsOrdered - TestsCompleted; }
        set
        {
            if (mTestsRemaining != value)
            {
                mTestsRemaining = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestsRemaining"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

MyContext is the DataContext that holds a ViewModel object.

XAML:

```
 <Grid Margin="-1,-9,1,9">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="244*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="251*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Width="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="96.791,40,54,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <Button x:Name="btnName" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="171,210,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" Height="47" Click="btnName_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="97,84,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=TestsOrdered}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="97,112,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=TestsCompleted}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="97,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=TestsRemaining}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code example of when you bind the property in xaml?

Comment: Also, what is `MyContext`?

Comment: Hi Nautilous.  I have added some of the XAML.  I am under the impression that I assign the Binding Path in XAML and WPF takes care of the rest behind the scenes.  What am I missing ?

Comment: You are correct, but you place the view model instance on the wrong property of your window instance. The `Binding` class uses the `Window` property: `DataContext` as it's default object to bind to. You could say that the full path of your bindings are `<WindowInstance>.DataContext.<PathDefinded>`. The Solution is to set your view model instance on the property `DataContext`. I'll write a answer to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your Bindings and your Properties are correctly written. However the issue is in your assignment of the viewmodel instance to the `Window`. You need to set the instance of your viewmodel on the property `DataContext` for the bindings to work. Like this:

```
 public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new ViewModel();
    //ct = new CompletionTime();
    //ct.TestsOrdered = 8000;

    vm.Name = "John Doe";
    vm.TestsCompleted = 0;
    vm.TestsOrdered = 0;
    vm.TestsRemaining = 0;

    //this.MyContext.DataContext = vm;
    this.DataContext = vm; // <-- Like so
}
```

The reason is the way bindings work. If no other source (`Source`, `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` properties of `Binding`) are provided, bindings will use the `DataContext` property of the `FrameworkElement` they are assigned to. In your case the `TextBox`.

When you set the `DataContext` property of the Window, then all it's child objects inherit that object instance, and their children, and so on.

Try to change your ViewModel assignment and you will see the bindings work.

//Cheers

Comment: Hi Nautious.  I changed it as you have mentioned.  The weird thing is that it still does not calculate / bind until I tab out of the last textbox.  I'm still missing something.

Comment: Okay.  I see what was wrong.  I was expecting all of the properties in the model to update.  I think I should have left the name property of EventArgs to null.

Comment: Okay, the binding now has a connection to the property. The new issue is it's way of updating. Change the bindings to include this: `UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged`. The default for textbox is `LostFocus`.

Comment: An empty property name in the EventArgs will trigger an update of all bindings.

Comment: Technically it's perfectly valid to set the context to another element, as long as he uses `x:Name="MyContext"` on said element, which from above XAML Code can't be said for sure he did it or not, as it only shows a fragment of the whole XAML code